# Robot Framework: Populating parameters based off of a robot.properties file?

Tags: robotframework, properties-file

I am attempting to mock-up a 'robot.properties' file to be utilized within my test cases with the Robot Framework. Inside my robot.properties file it contains things like for example:

```
project.username=stackoverflow
```

inside my test case file I have tried several times to 'import' the robot.properties file via adding within Settings: Resource  ../path/to/properties and etc (see directory structure below), but when I attempt to pass 'project.username' as an argument to a test it passes it as the literal string value 'project.username' and not the value 'stack overflow'. I am new to Robot, I have implemented this in other languages like Java/C#, but I fully assume that the import is preventing me from accessing my value. Any help would be greatly appreciated, unfortunately this way of driving testing isn't really referenced much online that I can find.

Dir Structure:

Tests/Acceptance/MyTestCase.robot

Tests/robot.properties

If I try Library  ../robot.properties I get:
"Import by filename is not supported"
If I try Resource ../robot.properties I get:
"Unsupported file format .properties"

Comment: why not use robot file as a source of variables? e.g. file `properties.robot` that has `*** Variables ***\n     ${project_username}  stackoverflow`? Such file can be imported with `Resource properties.robot`

Comment: Great response @jim, although this technique is certainly doable I favor the latter answer simply because it adheres more tightly to the properties '.' standard notation. Again, great effort and fast response!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Robot framework doesn't support a ".properties" file.

One solution is to use a [variable file](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#variable-files), which lets you define variables in python. Since you want to use dot notation, one way is to create a class and define your variables as properties of the class. The variable file can then make an instance of that class as a variable, and you can use [extended variable syntax](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#extended-variable-syntax) to access the variables.

The advantage to using a variable file over a plain text file is that you can create variables dynamically by calling other python functions. As a simple example, you could create a variable called "now" that contains the current date, or "host" that is the hostname of the machine running the test.

Example:

#### properties.py

```
import platform
class Properties(object):
    username = "stackoverflow"
    password = "SuperSecret!"
    hostname = platform.uname()[1]

properties = Properties()
```

#### example.robot

```
*** Settings ***
Variables    properties.py
Suite Setup  log    running on ${properties.hostname}

*** Test Cases ***
Example
    should be equal    ${properties.username}    stackoverflow
```

Comment: exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for the fast reply, Solid community support!!